# How can we set backgound color for <a> tag when I hover on <div> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some listings. At present when page loads listing is showing like

- Img 1
- Test 1
- Img 2
- Test 2
- Img 3
- Test 3

`Img` is in `<a>` tag and `test` content is in `<div>` tag

What I need is, when I hover on the `<div>` I need to set background color to `<a>`. That means,

If I mouse hover on `Test 1` a background color will add to `Img 1`,

If I mouse hover on `Test 2` a background color will add to `Img 2`,

If I mouse hover on `Test 3` a background color will add to `Img 3`,

How can I do that with the help of jquery?

In `<div>` tag there is `data-id`. In `<a>` tag there is `data-tag-id`.

```js
$('.description').each(function() {
  var dataId = $(this).attr("id").split('-')[1];
  $(this).attr('data-id', dataId);
}).click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
});


$('.area').each(function() {
  var dataId = $(this).attr("data-description-id").split('-')[1];
  $(this).attr('data-tag-id', dataId);
}).click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('tag-id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="image_container">
  <img src="files/maier-energie-umwelt/produkte/phantom-ruehrwerke/Phantom-1400.jpg" alt="" width="738" height="800">
  <figcaption class="caption">
    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Verschleißfester Propeller aus PA12" data-description-id="areaDesc-1" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 14.228%;top: 1.25%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker.png);" data-tag-id="1"></a>
    <div id="areaDesc-1" class="description invisible" data-id="1" style="display: block;">
      <p><strong>Test1</p>
    </div>

    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Abgedeckte doppelte Gleitringdichtung" data-description-id="areaDesc-2" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 25.745%;top: 21.875%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker.png);" data-tag-id="2"></a>
    <div id="areaDesc-2" class="description invisible" data-id="2">
      <p>Test2</p>
    </div>

    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Optimierte Schutzschelle aus Edelstahl" data-description-id="areaDesc-3" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 27.778%;top: 49.375%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker-bottom.png);" data-tag-id="3"></a>

    <div id="areaDesc-3" class="description invisible" data-id="3">
      <p>Test3</p>
    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use [**.hover()**](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) with your `.description` div elements combined with [**.prev()**](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous `a` elements and then change their background.

This is how should be your code:

```
$('.description').hover(function() {
  $(this).prev('a').css('background', "#f99");
}, function() {
  $(this).prev('a').css('background', "");
});
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo snippet:

```js
$('.description').hover(function() {
  $(this).prev('a').css('background', "#f99");
}, function() {
  $(this).prev('a').css('background', "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="image_container">
  <img src="files/maier-energie-umwelt/produkte/phantom-ruehrwerke/Phantom-1400.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
  <figcaption class="caption">
    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Verschleißfester Propeller aus PA12" data-description-id="areaDesc-1" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 14.228%;top: 1.25%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker.png);"
      data-tag-id="1">Link 0</a>
    <div id="areaDesc-1" class="description invisible" data-id="1" style="display: block;">
      <p><strong>Test1</p>
    </div>

    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Abgedeckte doppelte Gleitringdichtung" data-description-id="areaDesc-2" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 25.745%;top: 21.875%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker.png);" data-tag-id="2">Link 1</a>
    <div id="areaDesc-2" class="description invisible" data-id="2">
      <p>Test2</p>
    </div>

    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Optimierte Schutzschelle aus Edelstahl" data-description-id="areaDesc-3" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 27.778%;top: 49.375%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker-bottom.png);" data-tag-id="3">Link 2</a>

    <div id="areaDesc-3" class="description invisible" data-id="3">
      <p>Test3</p>
    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: as i pointer in the other response, using `("background-color", "")` will allow to keep css default background color instead of overriding it inline with white (maybe background color is not #fff)

Comment: @Diego well pointed out, I just assumed it was white. I am editing it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$('.description').on("hover", function() {
  $(this).prev().css("background-color", "red");;
}, function() {
  $(this).prev().css("background-color", "none");;
});
```

Comment: Care with duplicated `;;`. Futhermore, I'd change `$(this).prev().css("background-color", "none");` to `$(this).prev().css("background-color", "");`, so you can keep your css background color if exists, otherwise you will override it inline with `style="backgrounc-color:none"`

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. And actually, `.on("hover", fct())` doesn't even exists. The good answer is the one from @chsdk with `.hover()`

Comment: sure, you are right too, but you can use `$("#elem").on({"mousenter":function(){...},"mouseleave":function{...})` exactly as `$("#elem").hover(function(){...},function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
      $('[data-id]').hover(
         //executed when mouse is entering the object    
         function () {
                $("[data-tag-id=" + $(this).data('id') + "]").css('background', 'background-url-here');
            }, 
         //executed when mouse is leaving the object   
         function () {
                $("[data-tag-id=" + $(this).data('id') + "]").css('background', 'none');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get your result with CSS only, if using css sibling selector.

let's say we have this html :

```
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1" />
</div>
<div class="content">
        <h3>Test 1</h3>
</div>


<div class="img">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2"/>
</div>
<div class="content">
        <h3>Test 2</h3>
</div>


<div class="img">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/3"/>
</div>
<div class="content">
        <h3>Test 3</h3>
</div>
```

Then we can  use this in css :

```
.img:hover + .content{
  background-color:gray;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/wxn8vpyj/1/